# Get value of unknown class field

Tags: java, class, reflection, field

I have bunch of unknown classes that stored in `List`/`Array`.
How to get the value of fields from these classes?

What should I paste in `f.get()` ?

```
for(Class<?> cl : ClassList){
        for(Field f : cl.getFields()){
            try {
                f.setAccessible(true);
                writeln(f.get( <WHAT TO PASTE HERE> ));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Other libraries is good, but i cant use any files except my main jar    
Also i cant make new instance of that unknown class. That unknown class is Plugin class of Bukkit API

Comment: Please clarify what exactly do you want to do? It is not possible to read instance fields without actual instances (i.e. Objects). If you only have `Class`es, you will only be able to read static field values. Maybe you have a collection of the instances of the classes from `classList`? Or there is no classList but an objectList? I can write you an example in Java Reflection API but I have to understand the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as reflection is concerned, I prefer to rely on frameworks with more readable API then the standard Java Reflection API.  I've used two:

The first one is [**Mirror**](http://projetos.vidageek.net/mirror/mirror/). Getting fields values (either static or instance) looks like this:

Getting value of a static field:

```
Class clazz;
Object value = new Mirror().on(clazz).get().field("fieldName");
```

Getting value of a instance field:

```
Object target;
Object value = new Mirror().on(target).get().field("fieldName");
```

You can also pass a java.lang.reflect.Field instead of fieldName String.

Getting value of a static field:

```
Field aField;
Class clazz;
Object value = new Mirror().on(clazz).get().field(aField);
```

[**FEST-Reflect**](https://github.com/alexruiz/fest-reflect) is a another nice library ([FEST fluent Assertions](http://fest.easytesting.org/) are really nice, BTW).

```
import static org.fest.reflect.core.Reflection.*;

// Retrieves the value of the field "name"
String name = field("name").ofType(String.class).in(person).get();

// Retrieves the value of the field "powers"
List<String> powers = field("powers").ofType(new TypeRef<List<String>>() {})
                                     .in(jedi).get();

// Retrieves the value of the static field "count" in Person.class
int count = field("count").ofType(int.class).in(Person.class).get();


// Retrieves the value of the static field "commonPowers" in Jedi.class
List<String> commmonPowers = field("commonPowers")
                                    .ofType(new TypeRef<List<String>>() {})
                                    .in(Jedi.class).get();
```

All examples taken from the respective library's documentation.

Some quick and rough examples based on the code you've provided:
To achieve what you want (If I understand correctly) with Mirror:

```
for(Class<?> cl : classList){
   Mirror mirror = new Mirror().on(cl);
   for(Field f: mirror.reflectAll().fields()) {
      if(java.lang.reflect.Modifier.isStatic(f.getModifiers()) {
         writeln(mirror.get().field(f));
      }
   }
}
```

I've assumed that you want to read only static fields. For an Object list:

```
for(Object obj : objectList){
   for(Field f: new Mirror().on(obj.getClass()).reflectAll().fields()) {
       writeln(new Mirror().on(obj).get().field(f));
   }
}
```

The same with FEST-Reflect:

```
for(Class<?> cl : classList){
    for(Field f : cl.getFields()){
      if(java.lang.reflect.Modifier.isStatic(f.getModifiers()) {
         writeln(field(f.getName()).ofType(f.getType()).in(cl).get());
      }
    }
}
```

and:

```
for(Object obj : objectList){
   for(Field f: obj.getClass().getFields()) {
      if(!java.lang.reflect.Modifier.isStatic(f.getModifiers()) { //not 100% sure if this is required
         writeln(field(f.getName()).ofType(f.getType()).in(obj).get());
      }
   }
}
```

**Note** that you can't read instance filed values without an actual class instance (object) to read them from.

I hope this helps. The examples could use some refactoring, of course.

Answer (score 1):

The field that you have only points to a field, not to a particular field in a particular object, and you must have an object to get the field value from. The argument must be the object to extract the field value from. If the object is of the wrong type, an `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown. So be careful about that. Here's a snippet to illustrate:

```
Field field = Integer.class.getDeclaredField("value"); // I think that's the field name
int val = field.get(new Integer(8)); // returns 8
int val2 = field.get("Hello"); // throws IllegalArgumentException
```

Comment: Be sure to accompany your - otherwise correct - answer with a code snippet to make it more useful for future readers

Comment: The method `field.get(obj)` has an `Object` return type, so you would have to cast the returned value to an `Integer` or it would not compile. For primitive types, it is more convenient to use methods like `getInt()`.

Comment: That is true. I should have mentioned that.